# My name is not linkable in Github commits page

Tags: git, github, repository

I have been using Git Commit Tool to commit my local changes to Git repository.

But when i browse to the "Commits" page of my Github repository, i see that my name is not linkable, as shown in the below screenshot. Also, my image thumbnail is not showing up.

As a note, my Github username is different from the name shown on the page. I might have messed up with the Github settings before.

What config settings i need to make to get my name linkable in the page?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: [GitHub commits linked to wrong user](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user)

Your email setting needs to match the email address you are using on GitHub. You can update/change your email by using git config which is explained in the link I sent you.

Comment: There is no link in the answer. Please check.

Comment: If you read through the answer you should see this link:

[link(https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-email-in-git)]-in-git

Comment: This answer is probably correct. Make sure that one of the email addresses [configured in your GitHub profile](https://github.com/settings/emails) matches the email address in the commits (visible using `git log`, configured with `git config [--global] user.email`).

Answer (score 0):

Well, i found answer to my question, in the below URLs:

[Set email in GIT](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-email-in-git)

[Set username in GIT](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git)

I had to run the following commands in my Git Terminal:

```
git config --global user.name <my_github_username>

git config --global user.email <my_github_email>
```

I guess, someone must have run the above commands on my Git Terminal before.

But unfortunately, now i could not change the user names for the commits done in the past.
Don't know if there is a way to change them now.